# Find $\mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi U)\leq c)$

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

Find
$$IC=\mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi U)\leq c),$$
where $V\sim \Gamma(\alpha , \lambda)$ and $U\sim Beta(a,b)$, that is,
$f_V(v)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha) \lambda^\alpha} v^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{v}{\lambda}}1_{v>0}$ and
$f_U(u)=\frac{1}{Beta(a,b)}u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1}1_{(0,1)}(u)$. $V$ and $U$ are independent.

**1)** For a special case $a=b=1$, $\alpha=1$ and $\lambda=2$ the distribution of $\sqrt{V} \cos (\pi U)$ is standard normal.

**2)** For a special case $a=b=1$.  Let $c>0$

\begin{eqnarray}
IC &=& \mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi U)\leq c) 
\\ &=&  \int_0^{1} \mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi u)\leq c) f_U(u) du
\\ &=&  \int_0^{0.5} \mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi u)\leq c)  du
+\int_{0.5}^{1} \mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi u)\leq c)  du
\\ &=&  \int_0^{0.5} \mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \cos(\pi u)\leq c) du
+\int_{0.5}^{1} \mathbb 1 \quad  du
\\ &=&  \int_0^{0.5} \mathbb P(\sqrt{V} \leq \frac{c}{\cos(\pi u)}) du +\frac{1}{2}
\\ &=&  \int_0^{0.5} \frac{\gamma \left(\alpha , \frac{c^2}{\lambda^2 \cos^2(\pi u)} \right)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} du +\frac{1}{2} \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Where $\gamma$ is [Incomplete_gamma_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). For $c<0$ the solution is similar. Is it possible to simplify (2) or have a better solution ?

According to [square-root-of-a-gamma-distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293232/square-root-of-a-gamma-distribution), the distribution of $\sqrt{V}$ is [Nakagami_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution)

Any  special case is also useful.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: I do not know how to solve it yet, but at least the distribution of $\sqrt{V}$ is known: http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ChisquareChi.pdf

Comment: Set $X=\sqrt{V}$, $Y=\cos(\pi U)$, and $Z=XY$. Note $X$ and $Y$ inherit independence from $U$ and $V$. Furthermore, from delivery101's remark, the distribution of $X$ is known. We compute the pdf of $Y$ to be $$f_Y(y)=\frac{\big(\arccos(y)\big)^{\alpha-1}\big(\pi-\arccos(y)\big)^{\beta-1}}{\pi^{\alpha+\beta-1}B(\alpha,\beta)\sqrt{1-y^2}}\cdot 1_{(-1,1)}(y)$$ We have from independence and the total law of probability that $$IC=\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}P(XY\leq z|X=x)f_{X}(x)dx=\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty} F_{Y}(z/x)f_X(x)dx$$

Comment: @Matthew Holder, Thanks for attention. Can you go further? An answer required.

Comment: @delivery101, It was helpful. You right. I did  a little change to the question. (The $chi^2$ distribution replaced with Gamma distribution.)